# What are the files and directories installed for openjdk 8 for?

Tags: openjdk

I installed openjdk on Lubuntu 18.04 by

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

The files and directories it has installed under `/usr/lib/jvm/` for openjdk-8 are

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/jvm 
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 4096 May 20 22:52 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   20 Apr 26 11:59 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2600 Apr 26 11:59 .java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

What are the three files and directories for respectively?

In particular, what differences are between the two directories?

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/:
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 26 11:59 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Apr 26 11:59 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 include
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 jre
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 26 11:59 src.zip -> ../openjdk-8/src.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 26 11:59 THIRD_PARTY_README -> jre/THIRD_PARTY_README

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/:
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 26 11:59 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Apr 26 11:59 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 include
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 jre
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 20 23:08 man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 26 11:59 src.zip -> ../openjdk-8/src.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 26 11:59 THIRD_PARTY_README -> jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
```

Comment: What about hidden files. Try `ls -a` to see If any

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`?